# Sencha Touch 2 - setActiveItem animation doesnt work

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2, I use this code snippet in my controller:

```
        this.control({
        '#test_button': {           
            tap: function () {
                var root_c = Ext.getCmp("main_container");
                root_c.setActiveItem(
                    1, {type:'slide', direction: 'left'}
                );
            } 
        }           
    });
```

It works nicely, but it switches only the "default way", not the "sliding way". Can anyone help, why?

Thanks in advance,
R

Comment: This problem solved in here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192411-setActiveItem-animation-doesnt-work

Needs to use animateActiveItem instead of setActiveItem (only in ST2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others said, use animateActiveItem. Alternately you can keep your (single parameter) setActiveItem and also set a showAnimation and hidAnimation on the particular view being shown.

Having said that, this has been problematic in my experience if your shown items are nested with a lot of going back and forth.

**update**
I *just* discovered that there's an apparent timing bug in st2.0.1 such that if you use show/hideAnimation, you can't actually destroy the object that has the attribute set. Bit me hard. Related: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192847-Animating-panels-throws-Cannot-call-method-getPageBox-of-null

Answer (score 1):

In Sencha Touch 2, the proper method for your need is **animateActiveItem**

Answer (score 1):

```
  this.control({
    '#test_button': {           
      tap: function () {
        var root_c = Ext.getCmp("main_container");
          root_c.animateActiveItem(1, {type:'slide', direction: 'left'});
      } 
    }           
  });
```

In sencha touch 2 setActiveItem has only one parameter:

```
setActiveItem( Object/Number activeItem )
```

So you have to use:

```
animateActiveItem( Object/Number activeItem, Object/Ext.fx.layout.Card animation )
```

More info: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-animateActiveItem